# Get NA list using Map function based on condition in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(EnvStats)

DT <- data.table(MEAN = c(0.5,0.7,0.9,0.8),MIN = c(0.4,0.6,0.8,0.8),MAX = c(0.6,0.8,1,0.8),REF = rnorm(4,1000,200))
```

I compute a var containing a list of simulated values from vars `MEAN`, `MIN` and `MAX` but I need to return NA values if `MEAN <= MIN` or  `MEAN >= MAX`.
Something like this:

```
DT[, Sim_rtri := Map(function(w, x, y, z) ifelse(z <= x | z >= y,NA,w*(1+rtri(n = 10000,min = x,max = 
y,mode = z))), REF, MIN, MAX, MEAN)]
```

But I get an output with just a single value in all cases. Like this:

```
 DT
    MEAN MIN MAX       REF Sim_rtri
 1:  0.5 0.4 0.6 1274.1917 1957.572
 2:  0.7 0.6 0.8  887.0604 1503.418
 3:  0.9 0.8 1.0 1072.6257 2011.683
 4:  0.8 0.8 0.8 1126.5725       NA
```

Instead my desired output is:

```
DT
    MEAN MIN MAX       REF                                                Sim_rtri
 1:  0.5 0.4 0.6 1274.1917 1946.223,1849.996,1933.170,1940.845,1905.784,1943.204,...
 2:  0.7 0.6 0.8  887.0604 1512.938,1530.315,1480.203,1542.298,1500.740,1513.961,...
 3:  0.9 0.8 1.0 1072.6257 2055.113,2085.123,1991.335,2022.209,2010.288,1984.313,...
 4:  0.8 0.8 0.8 1126.5725 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,....
```

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we need `if/else` instead of `ifelse` as `ifelse` requires all arguments to be of same length, the `rtri` `n` is obviously large and is not of the same length as `test` vector which is of `length` 1 as we are looping on each row

```
DT[, Sim_rtri := Map(function(w, x, y, z) if(z <= x | z >= y) NA 
            else(w*(1+rtri(n = 10000,min = x,max = 
 y,mode = z))), REF, MIN, MAX, MEAN)]
DT
#   MEAN MIN MAX      REF                                                  Sim_rtri
#1:  0.5 0.4 0.6 1292.650 1894.088,1943.958,1935.992,1881.802,1918.530,1975.114,...
#2:  0.7 0.6 0.8 1037.545 1817.918,1742.029,1719.068,1753.283,1786.834,1803.231,...
#3:  0.9 0.8 1.0 1204.405 2327.954,2306.122,2198.317,2223.934,2235.752,2328.857,...
#4:  0.8 0.8 0.8  881.633                                                        NA
```

Also, if we need to have `n` NAs, just replicate the `NA` in `if`

```
if(z <= x | z >= y) rep(NA, 10000)
```